# NSDateFormatter dateFromString sometimes returns null

Tags: null, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my app i use this code for creating `NSDate` from `NSString`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmss"];

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:comment.created];

NSLog(@"comment.created %@ dateFromString %@",comment.created, dateFromString);
```

But for some string it returns null!

For input `20131031083130` it returns `2013-10-31 04:31:30`, when for `20131107200617` - `(null)`

```
StreetJournal[32054:60b] comment.created 20131031083130 dateFromString 2013-10-31 04:31:30 +0000
StreetJournal[32054:60b] comment.created 20131107200617 dateFromString (null)
```

Why?

Comment: I guess input string is different both times. Right? If yes, then please provide us with input strings.

Comment: @AkshitZaveri you can see it in logs at the end of post. But for your convenience i add explonation above

Comment: sorry for asking inputs. I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your dateformat to **`yyyyMMddHHmmss`**.

I don't know the difference between 'hh' & 'HH' but i know it's the right way to do it. I tested & it's working too.

**EDIT:**

As far as my experience **'hh' is for 12-hours** format & **'HH' is for 24-hours** format.